# How Do You Insert Large Blobs Into Oracle 10G Using System.Data.OracleClient?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, oracle10g, system.data.oracleclient

Trying to insert 315K Gif files into an Oracle 10g database.  Everytime I get this error "ora-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested" whe I run the stored procedure.  It appears that there is a 32K limit if I use a stored procedure.  I read online that this does not apply if you are doing a direct insert, but I do not know how to create the insert string for a Byte Array.  This is a thick client running on the server so not worried about SQL Injection attacks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  FYI, code in vb.net.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the snippet of VB.net code where you are attempting to insert the blob using the stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use System.Data.OracleClient. It has performance issues with BLOBs/CLOBs. Now it's deprecated by Microsoft and will not be supported. Instead of it, use Oracle's native ODP.NET.