# System.Data.OracleClient - write large string to Clob column

Tags: c#, oracle11g, clob

I'm trying to insert large string (over 4.000 characters) into Oracle Clob column, but I keep receiving error "**Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 30**". I've tried multiple things, but everything fails when String is longer than 4.000 characters. My last attempt is made from example at bottom [of this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oraclelob?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8): .

Here is my code, I changed DataType **Blob** to **Clob** (It doesn't work for Blob too):

```
 try
 {
   using (var conn = new OracleConnection(_conn))
   {
      conn.Open();
      OracleTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

      using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(SQL, conn))
      {
          cmd.Transaction = transaction;
          cmd.CommandText = "declare xx clob; begin dbms_lob.createtemporary(xx, false, 0); :tempblob := xx; end;";
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("tempblob", OracleType.Clob)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          OracleLob tempLob = (OracleLob)cmd.Parameters[0].Value;
          byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Large_string);
          tempLob.BeginBatch(OracleLobOpenMode.ReadWrite);
          tempLob.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
          tempLob.EndBatch();

          cmd.Parameters.Clear();
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("NAME_IN", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = String_1;
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("REASON_IN", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = String_2;
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ID", OracleType.Clob)).Value =tempLob; 
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      transaction.Commit();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
```

What am I missing here ?

P.S. : As stated in question title, I need solution for **System.Data.OracleClient**. Unfortunally I can't use **DataAccess.dll** (which probably solves problem,bump). For any help thanks in advance.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322178/clob-not-inserting-a-document-more-than-4000-characters-in-stored-procedure-from help?

Comment: @mjwills, I allready tried that solution, It didn't work for me.

Comment: @mjwills, my mistake, I didn't notice comment from Russel with link of answer I haven't seen so far. Now my insert works. Apparently the only issue was on how I call Transaction within connection. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Here is the answer that worked for me (accepted answer): [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557995/issues-calling-stored-procedure-from-c-sharp-with-large-clob?rq=1)